# Passing variable into included file

Tags: php, variables, scope, include

I made a simple framework to deepen my understanding regarding php.
In my controller, I write the below code to show view:

```
$varString = "test";
$varArray  = array("a", "b", "c");
include __DIR__ . './homepage.php';
```

The real weird thing is, both the variable is available inside the homepage.php file as I can get its value via var_dump.
But as I try to loop the $varArray using foreach as below:

```
<? foreach($varArray as $value): ?>
<?= $value; ?>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

I get the following error,

> Notice: Undefined variable: value

Also, adding to this confusion, there is no problem echoing $varString using echo like this:

```
<?= $varString; ?>
```

Anyone had the same issue as this before?
Note that I am doing all this inside the homepage.php file.

Comment: Bit of a sanity check, if you `var_dump($varArray);` what value do you get?

Comment: Why are you trying to jump in and out of PHP? Just use `<?php` on the first line and remove all of those `<?` and `?>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is php short tags open if you want you can use

```
<?php foreach($varArray as $value): ?>
<?php echo $value; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

or you can open php.ini short tag.

Comment: did you try it ?

Comment: This solved it!. As I can get all the variable using var_dump, this make sense that only the foreach part is the problem which is I didnot enable the short tag.

Answer (score 0):

This done as follows and should work

```
foreach($varArray as $value){
echo $value;
}
```

Try it as above and should work fine